# JS Function Scope with Ebay API

Tags: javascript, scope, callback, ebay-api

js beginner here. the ebay website has sample code for sending an api request with javascript. the code works out of the box, but the code breaks when i wrap the entire code inside of:

`(document).ready( function() {
    ('button').click( function() {
        //(ebays sample code here)
        }); });`

google chromes console says my error is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _cb_findItemsByKeywords is not defined
at http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=micahelr-layitont-PRD-f51ca6568-6366e278&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=accord&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=5&itemFilter(0).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(0).value=30&itemFilter(0).paramName=USD&itemFilter(1).name=ListingType&itemFilter(1).value(0)=AuctionWithBIN&itemFilter(1).value(1)=FixedPrice:1:5
(anonymous) @ svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=micahelr-layitont-PRD-f51ca6568-6366e278&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=accord&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=5&itemFilter(0).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(0).value=30&itemFilter(0).paramName=USD&itemFilter(1).name=ListingType&itemFilter(1).value(0)=AuctionWithBIN&itemFilter(1).value(1)=FixedPrice:1
```

what i have come up with, is that the scope of my callback function is incorrect. ive moved the `.ready()` and `.click()` statements in many different places within the script tags, trying to solve the problem without completely understanding how it can be fixed. i tried reading about function scope but it seems like its something that i just cant figure out. the following is the content of mt HTML file with embedded JS code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button>click</button>   


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('button').click( function() {


var urlfilter = "";
item_MaxPrice = Number(document.getElementById('pagePrice').innerHTML);    
inputKeywords = 'accord';


var filterarray = [ {"name":"MaxPrice", "value":item_MaxPrice, "paramName":"USD"}, ];


function _cb_findItemsByKeywords(root) {
    var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
    var html = [];
    html.push('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        var item = items[i];
        html.push('text here');};
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html.join("");};



// Generates an indexed URL snippet from the array of item filters
function  buildURLArray() {
    for(var i=0; i<filterarray.length; i++) {
        var itemfilter = filterarray[i];
        for(var index in itemfilter) {
            if (itemfilter[index] !== "") {
            if (itemfilter[index] instanceof Array) {
            for(var r=0; r<itemfilter[index].length; r++) {
                var value = itemfilter[index][r];
                urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "\(" + r + "\)=" + value ;
      }
    }
    else {
      urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "=" + 
itemfilter[index];
    }}}}}



// Execute the function to build the URL filter
buildURLArray(filterarray);    


var url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
    url += "?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
    url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0";
    url += "&SECURITY-APPNAME=micahelr-layitont-PRD-f51ca6568-6366e278";
    url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US";
    url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
    url += "&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords";
    url += "&REST-PAYLOAD";
    url += "&keywords="+inputKeywords;
    url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=5";
    url += urlfilter;


s=document.createElement('script'); // create script element
s.src= url;
document.body.appendChild(s);    
document.write("<a href='" + url + "'>" + url + "</a>");
})});
</script>

</body>
<footer>&copy;darnell cross 2018</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Makes reasoning about scope a lot easier.

Comment: how do i even properly indent javascript code? i use brackets as my editor and it seems like getting consistent indentation is so hard to do, it seems like it must not be at all important. not to mention stackoverflow seems to inconsistently format my code as well. i am coming from a background in python.

Comment: Sounds like you use the wrong editor or have misconfigured it, indentation is very important for readability - just like in Python. StackOverflow on the other hand doesn't format your code at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: _cb_findItemsByKeywords is not defined

You are getting this error because Javascript can't find the *_cb_findItemsByKeywords* function.

What is the problem?

You are creating a script element and adding it to the DOM which is having *_cb_findItemsByKeywords* function as a callback in the URL.

> s=document.createElement('script'); // create script element s.src=
>   url; document.body.appendChild(s);     document.write("" + url + "");

Now, the script would run in the global context and wouldn't find any *_cb_findItemsByKeywords* function there because you defined it inside of another function.

`$(document).ready(function() {...}`

(Remember: Every function creates it's own context)

Solution:

Add the *_cb_findItemsByKeywords* function to the window object.

```
window._cb_findItemsByKeywords = function() {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps you understand scope with indentation levels. Normally when you indent you use it to help you visualize the levels of scope. A variable declared in a parent scope can be accessed in the child but not the other way around.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button>click</button>


  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $('button').click(function() {

              //start of scope
              var urlfilter = "";
              item_MaxPrice = Number(document.getElementById('pagePrice').innerHTML);
              inputKeywords = 'accord';


              var filterarray = [{
                "name": "MaxPrice",
                "value": item_MaxPrice,
                "paramName": "USD"
              }, ];


              function _cb_findItemsByKeywords(root) {                           
                var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
                var html = [];
                html.push('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">

                  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
                     //start of new scope (can access everything in parent scope but nothing in a scope that is further nested    
                    var item = items[i];
                    html.push('text here');
                    //end of new scope
                  }; document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html.join("");
                };



                // Generates an indexed URL snippet from the array of item filters
                function buildURLArray() {
                  for (var i = 0; i < filterarray.length; i++) {
                    var itemfilter = filterarray[i];
                    for (var index in itemfilter) {
                      if (itemfilter[index] !== "") {
                        if (itemfilter[index] instanceof Array) {
                          for (var r = 0; r < itemfilter[index].length; r++) {
                            var value = itemfilter[index][r];
                            urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "\(" + r + "\)=" + value;
                          }
                        } else {
                          urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "=" +
                            itemfilter[index];
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }



                // Execute the function to build the URL filter
                buildURLArray(filterarray);


                var url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
                url += "?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
                url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0";
                url += "&SECURITY-APPNAME=micahelr-layitont-PRD-f51ca6568-6366e278";
                url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US";
                url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
                url += "&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords";
                url += "&REST-PAYLOAD";
                url += "&keywords=" + inputKeywords;
                url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=5";
                url += urlfilter;


                s = document.createElement('script'); // create script element
                s.src = url;
                document.body.appendChild(s);
                document.write("<a href='" + url + "'>" + url + "</a>");
              })
          //end of button scope
          });
  </script>

</body>
<footer>&copy;darnell cross 2018</footer>

</html>
```